# Java monitor file system when java is not running

Tags: java, filesystemwatcher, java-7

I recently implemented Java 7's WatchService and it works perfectly. Now I wondered if there is a way to get all the Events which occured since the last run of my program. For example:

1. I run my program, create some files, edit some files and I get all the corresponding Events
2. I close my program
3. I create a file named `foo.txt`
4. I start my program, and the first event i get is an `ENTRY_CREATE` for `foo.txt`

I thought about saving the `lastModifiedDate` and searching for files and directorys newer than the last execution of my program. Is there another (and better) way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no better way to do this if your program is meant to scan for **all** file changes (apart from storing files in a content / source control repository, but that would be external to your program).

Java 7's `WatchService` is only a more performant way than continuously looping and comparing file dates / folder contents, hence you need to implement your own logic to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in Java, or in any other programming language.

The operating system doesn't (and can't) buffer file system events on the off-chance that someone might start a program to process them.  The event monitor / delivery system captures the events for a running application that is listening for them.  When nothing is listening, the events are not captured.

Comment: Yeah thats kinda obvious and not what i meant with my Question, i hoped that Java has a workaround implementation somewhere (like an impelentation of the lastModifiedDate solution or something)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small daemon (system service on Windows) which runs continuously and listens for file system changes. It could write these to a file. When your application runs, rather than listening for changes itself, it could just read the file. As events happen while it runs, the daemon will continue to receive them and send them through the file to the application.

You would need to ensure that the file was organised in such a way that it could be written to and read from safely at the same time, and that it did not grow indefinitely.